# username and password not working after transfering magento to another server

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, database

the username and password for the administration is not working after we transfer magento to another server, we just export the database from the previous server and import to our current. Can you help me to fix this. thank you

**UPDATE 22/07/2015**

I have manage to fix this problem by dumping the database and deleting the `app/etc/local.xml` and `var/cache/all_folder` and doing the installation...

Comment: what is happening? Are you getting any errors? Does your url become longer and see a white screen or something?

Comment: no, it only show Invalid User Name or Password. i already change local.xml to our current database.

Comment: try deleting the local.xml it will start a new installation which fixes a lot of settings. You are also able to create a new admin account. you should think of backing up your database before you do this. It mostly fixes a lot of issues. You wont lose your products, customers categorys's etc etc. you might also want to use the same security key, its in your local.xml

Comment: do i also need to delete the data inside var/cache??

Comment: preferrably yes, if you change a lot of things or important things its a good idea to delete of refresh the cache

Comment: it work! thank you! can i ask you another question sir? the template and css is not working after we transfer it to our current server. do you know any solution?thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26054/discussion-between-frosit-and-user3779015).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of issue usually happens when moving from local to live, or switching domain. Its because we have Base URL and other Skin and Media URLS in admin panel set according to our previous file structure. The settings are found in **System** > **Configuration** > **Web** under **Secure** tab

So before dumping the database, maybe all you will need to do is change these values from database manually, and it might work for you. In database, the values are stored in "**core_config_data**" table, and change the values where **path** column is **web/unsecure/base_url** and **web/secure/base_url**